# Chi-Squared for data from pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, chi-squared

I need to calculate the Chi-Squared of

```
 CAT    Label
0   A   0.0
1   A   0.0
2   B   1.0
4   A   0.0
6   B   0.0
... ... ...
3566    C   0.0
3567    A   0.0
3568    B   0.0
3571    C   1.0
```

I have been using cross tab:

```
data = pd.crosstab(df['CAT'],df['Label'], margins = False)
```

I am getting the following:

```
Label   0.0 1.0
CAT     
A   425 37
B   718 82
C   637 128
```

Calculating the Chi-Square, I am getting the following results:

```
contingency = pd.crosstab(df['CAT'], df['Label'])
stat, p, dof, expected = chi2_contingency(contingency)

alpha = 0.05

print('Significance=%.3f, p=%.3f' % (alpha, p))
if p <= alpha:
    print('-> Variables are associated')
else:
    print('-> Variables are not associated')
```

The result is

```
Significance=0.050, p=0.000
Variables are associated.
```

Do you think it is right the approach and the results are reliable? I am getting a p_value=0.000 also when I check a different variable. I am wondering if, since I have A, B, and C, I cannot apply the Chi-Squared in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are limiting the number of decimal places to 3. Chances are your p-value is much smaller and rounds up to 0.000. Try changing the format of p to '.5g' for example and maybe that'll display even small values of p.

Comment: Thank you Carlos. So it is right to use the Chi-Squared in this case, isn't it?

Comment: It really depends what is your null hypothesis. Making decisions based just on the p-values can be tricky. I found this article very helpful: https://towardsdatascience.com/what-is-p-value-short-for-no-seriously-c548200660a